# Prove that if a $\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $a^{3} \equiv a(mod 3)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove that if a $\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $a^{3} \equiv a(mod 3)$

So, the ways I have learned (or am learning, rather) to do proofs is using direct, contrapositive and contradiction.

So, I started it using direct, and got this:

$n|(a^{3}-a)$

Then there exists an integer k such that:

$nk = a^{3} - a$

$nk = a(a^{2} - 1)$

$nk = a(a+1)(a-1)$

so a must be -1, 0 or 1.

And there is where I'm stuck. I don't know where to go next and I'm not sure if it would be easier to use another method, maybe contradiction? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below. How many factors are there? What is their relationship to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try factoring $a^3−a$. What do you notice about the relationship of the factors to each other? How many are there? What can you then conclude?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18170/discussion-between-user1282637-and-user4894).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18186/discussion-on-answer-by-user4894-prove-that-if-a-in-mathbbz-then-a3-e).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great.  You can also break this into cases.  For any integer $a$, we must have:

$a \equiv \text{0, 1, or 2} \pmod{3}$.

Considering each case, we have:

$$0^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$1^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^3 \equiv 8 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$$

More generally, I'd recommend reading up on [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).